# Read CSV file and put result in a map using Grails / Groovy

Tags: java, csv, grails, groovy

Im using the code below to read a csv file and would like to put result in a map

```
def fileName = 'C:/temp/exampleCSV.csv'
        def reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)))
        def header = reader.readNext()
        def rows = reader.readAll().collect { row ->
            (0..(row.size()-1)).collectEntries { [header[it], row[it]] }
        }
```

CSV:

```
name;cuInfo;service;startDate;appId
Apple;T12;3;14-02-16 10:00;G12351
Apple;T13;3;14-01-16 13:00;G12352
Google;T14;9;10-01-16 11:20;G12301
Microsoft;T15;10;26-02-16 10:20;G12999
```

But the code above give me the output:

```
  [
        [name;cuInfo;service;startDate;appId:Apple;T12;3;14-02-16 10:00;G12351], 
        [name;cuInfo;service;startDate;appId:Apple;T13;3;14-01-16 13:00;G12352], 
        [name;cuInfo;service;startDate;appId:Google;T14;9;10-01-16 11:20;G12301], 
        [name;cuInfo;service;startDate;appId:Microsoft;T15;10;26-02-16 10:20;G12999]
    ]
```

I would like to get this structure as the map below?

```
[
        [name:"Apple", cuInfo:"T12",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:22",appId:"G12355"],
        [name:"Apple",cuInfo:"T13",service:"3",startDate:"12-02-16 13:00",appId:"G12356"],
        [name:"Google",cuInfo:"T14",service:"9",startDate:"10-01-16 11:20",appId:"G12300"], 
        [name:"Microsoft",cuInfo:"T15",service:"10",startDate:"26-02-16 10:20",appId:"G12999"]  
    ]
```

Comment: what is your problem here?

Comment: @droggo, I would to find difference between data coming from DB and  and csv and create new csv with difference

Comment: so compare it and print to file. I don't see any specific problem to solve in this question

Comment: @user3122166 show your current solution for this problem.

Comment: @MichalSzulc, Sure I thought about it, I edited my code above, the problem is how to get the data from the csv in the same structure as data coming from the database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the data from the CSV file into the same structure (a list of Maps) as the query output, you can do this:

```
def reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)))
def output = reader.collect { it[0].split(';') }.with { rows ->
    def header = rows.head()
    def dataRows = rows.tail()

    dataRows.collect { row ->
        [header, row].transpose().collectEntries()
    }
}
```

The CSV rows are split into columns, the header and the remaining rows are gathered, and then they are transformed.

The `transpose()` creates a structure like this for each data row:

```
[[name, Apple], [cuInfo, T12], [service, 3], [startDate, 14-02-16 10:00], [appId, G12351]]
```

And `collectEntries()` turns this into a `Map`:

```
[name:Apple, cuInfo:T12, service:3, startDate:14-02-16 10:00, appId:G12351]
```

Comment: @Rosa, Great works!!!,Thanks,  my other question how can I compare this maps and find difference in Grails please see my example above

Comment: Great question! But on StackOverflow you get to ask one question at a time. Besides, this is not really a **Grails** question. So go ahead and ask a new **Groovy** question with your two identically-structured example `Map`s sourced from the database and CSV file.

Comment: @Rosa you right, i will do that and accept your answer

Comment: I'm trying this code, and I'm getting Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead. With code written like this, how can I protect myself from nulls? (Or even just treat everything like a string)

Comment: You can use the Groovy safe navigation operator: http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator

Comment: of which groovy version are u guys talking? i need to read a csv file aswell but my groovy version 2.4.7 doesnt provide CSVReader

Comment: `CSVReader` doesn't come with Groovy, it's from a third-party library. I believe it's part of OpenCSV: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: For anyone using a CSV file separated by Commas (crazy, i know), skip the `collect` step. The second line will then read `def output = reader.with { rows ->`